# Why is Entity Framework behaving as expected in a MVC app and totally diferent in a WebAPI?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I've been working with Entity Framework 6 for some time now and today I started with a new Web API project and as soon as I execute a query that includes some other entity I receive an error like this:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

The thing and do not understand is that, when I used the same Eager Loading while running a regular MVC App it will bring me exactly what I need, nothing else.

So far this is the relevant code I'm working with:

Beer.cs

```
public class Beer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public int BrandId { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Brand.cs

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Beer> Beers { get; set;} = null!;
}
```

BeerRepository.cs

```
public class BeerRepository : IBeerRepository
{
    private readonly BeerContext _context;

    public BeerRepository(BeerContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task CreateBeerAsync(Beer beer)
    {
        if(beer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(beer));

        await _context.Beers.AddAsync(beer);
    }

    //BUG: This is the one causing me issues!
    public async Task<ICollection<Beer>> GetAsync() => await _context.Beers.Include(b => b.Brand).ToListAsync();

    public async Task<Beer> GetByIdAsync(int id) => await _context.Beers.FirstAsync(b => b.Id == id);

    public async Task SavaChangesAsync()
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

BeerContext.cs

```
#nullable disable
public partial class BeerContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Beer> Beers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }

    public BeerContext(DbContextOptions opt) : base(opt)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //BEER ENTITY
        modelBuilder.Entity<Beer>(entity => {
            entity.HasData(
                new Beer { Id = 1, BrandId = 1, Name = "Torobayo" },
                new Beer { Id = 2, BrandId = 1, Name = "Bock" },
                new Beer { Id = 3, BrandId = 1, Name = "Lager Sin Filtrar" },
                new Beer { Id = 4, BrandId = 2, Name = "Super Dry" },
                new Beer { Id = 5, BrandId = 2, Name = "Soukai" }
            );
        });

        //BRAND ENTITY
        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>(entity => {
            entity.HasData(
                new Brand{ Id = 1, Name = "Kunstman" },
                new Brand{ Id = 2, Name = "Asahi" }
            );
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

BeersController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BeersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBeerRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public BeersController(IMapper mapper, IBeerRepository repository)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BeerReadDTO>>> GetAllBeers()
    {
        var beers = await _repository.GetAsync();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BeerReadDTO>>(beers));
    }
}
```

I also changed the Program.cs file like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt => {
    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

It works (at least it will remove the error) but instead I'm getting this "nice" data!

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Torobayo",
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kunstman",
      "beers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Torobayo",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Bock",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Lager Sin Filtrar",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bock",
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kunstman",
      "beers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Torobayo",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Bock",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Lager Sin Filtrar",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Lager Sin Filtrar",
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kunstman",
      "beers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Torobayo",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Bock",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Lager Sin Filtrar",
          "brandId": 1,
          "brand": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Super Dry",
    "brand": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Asahi",
      "beers": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Super Dry",
          "brandId": 2,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Soukai",
          "brandId": 2,
          "brand": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Soukai",
    "brand": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Asahi",
      "beers": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Super Dry",
          "brandId": 2,
          "brand": null
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Soukai",
          "brandId": 2,
          "brand": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This is the query running in the background...

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (49ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[BrandId], [b].[Name], [b0].[Id], [b0].[Name]
      FROM [Beers] AS [b]
      INNER JOIN [Brands] AS [b0] ON [b].[BrandId] = [b0].[Id]
```

And what I actually need is this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Torobayo",
    "brand":"Kunstman"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bock",
    "brand":"Kunstman"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Lager Sin Filtrar",
    "brand":"Kunstman"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Super Dry",
    "brand":"Asahi"
  },
]
```

Any help will be a good start since I ran out of ideas. Thank you very much!

EDIT:
So, i decided to also post my DTO File and also the Automapper configuration... looks like it is not clear that i'm actually mapping from Beer entity to the corresponding DTO.

BeerReadDTO.cs

```
public class BeerReadDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapperConf.cs

```
public class AutoMapperConf : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConf()
    {
        // Source -> Target
        CreateMap<Beer,BeerReadDTO>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not expose your entity classes, create a DTO with the desired shape and map to it.

Comment: If you returns `BeerReadDTO`, then change it to match your JSON and map it properly.

Comment: I don't get how am I not mapping here... if you read the BeersController.cs file you will see clearly that i'm mapping from the entity to a DTO (using automapper). Just in case i also edited the original post adding the AutoMapperConf.cs and BeerReadDTO.cs files.

Comment: @AcidRod75 that is because of the unwanted navigation properties. If you get the record without doing the automapping then debug the result you will get to know which navigation properties are loading. You have to minimize that and then automap them

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. thanks to [Kamran Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4963996/kamran-khan) who pointed me in the right direction!... the issue was fixed just by removing the navigation property from Brands to Beers and changing the Brands for the DTO to a string.

Here are the files i changed and it worked fine!

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    //public virtual ICollection<Beer> Beers { get; set;} = null!;
}

public class BeerReadDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}

public class AutoMapperConf : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConf()
    {
        // Source -> Target
        CreateMap<Beer,BeerReadDTO>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Brand, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Brand.Name));
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!